# GORM Stale object exception

Tags: grails, grails-orm

While inserting a record to domain object we were getting error:

```
Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect) 
Stacktrace follows:
org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect)
```

We have a simple domain :

```
User{
    String uid
    String firstName
    String lastName
}
```

While doing :

```
def user=new User(uid:"TestUser", firstName:"Test", lastName:"User")
```

we are getting the above error.

Comment: One thing we find is our database table has one more field whose constraint is not null and not mapped to our domain.

Comment: This is resolved after we added below:

Comment: id name: "userId" , generator: 'assigned' 
        userId column :"UID"

Comment: // generator required for inserting record in db

Comment: new User(uid:"TestUser",firstName:"Test",lastName:"User").save () ? You are missed by .save

Comment: Typically you will see this when you gave segmented code that attempts that  update the same record and save simultaneously. You can add User.withTransaction { around the specific bits to see if changes. Or remove the various saves and have an. Overall save that happens after all segments called. Passing user object across